# NHibernate Spatial official source control 

Tags: nhibernate, oracle-spatial

anyone knows where is the official source control system for nHibernate Spatial?
In GitHub there is one, but the source is diffent from nhforge.org, and the last doesn't support OracleSpatial. The GitHub's is not "compilable". Any ideas where to find the official?

Answer (score 1):

The SVN repository is at: https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Spatial

Hasn't been updated in a while...

Comment: So is part of ncontrib, nice. Thanks. I'll take a look into it.

Comment: It has the same problem as the one in GitHub, With Oracle spatial is not compilable :(

Comment: That's a shame... Unfortunately this project hasn't had much atention lately.

Comment: Well, almost an year has passed, but I've added a blog post on how to correctly compile NHibernate Spatial: http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/02/nhibernate-spatial-part-1.html